# Binding/Auto-Updating charts in Word document with data from MS SQL Server

Tags: database, excel, charts, ms-word, auto-update

I've a task wherein I'm required to work with Microsoft Word document and database. Basically the word document has numerous charts that are created by users in two steps, first is to prepare charts in excel, then take screenshot and paste in Word document. It's tedious process as it requires re-doing charts anytime someone wants to do what-if simulations.

When I insert a chart in Word, the underlying data comes from Excel Sheet which I am able to fetch from database as 1 time operation, but it's not productive that much as users will have to open excel sheet, refresh data in sheet manually.

I tried to find different solutions but I'm blank as it's totally new work for me, there are elementary examples suggesting VSTO but I couldn't find more detailed examples specifically for charts like the scenario I've.

Has anyone tackled similar issue? If so please advise. I'm open to use either VSTO, OpenXML or even R packages that can help to auto-generate word document with updated charts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by using R, it satisfies what I was looking for. A related task and steps are in my other question are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952018/r-reporters-package-word-template-with-dynamic-values)!